# Get non duplicate random element using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario, where I need to find a random winner from a group of entries.

The entries can be multiple times and now I am fetching all the records grouped by user ID and using PHP's array_rand() method to find a  random winner. The grouping is used to avoid duplicate elements.

Here I am facing two problems

1. The query is timing out as it is dealing with almost 10000000 records.
2. PHP memory is exhausted because of large number of records.

My current query is a simple one and it looks like this

```
SELECT id, userID from table where id!= 1111 and created_at >='2017-08-10' group by userID
```

What is the best method, which will work on this large-scale?

Comment: Well, if you want only one user you can added a `limit 0,1`. Finally you want only one :)

Comment: But this might not be random

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY RAND()` and limit results to 1 to avoid memory getting exhausted.

```
SELECT id, userID
from table
where id!= 1111 and created_at >='2017-08-10'
group by userID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ah. let `mySQL` do it for you. +1

Comment: This will work, but it is taking around 22 seconds to get the query completed when it is running directly on the server. So I think the delay will increase once we take network transport delay into consideration. But yeah, it will return only one record.

Comment: If the table is large its normal that it will take few sec since your using range in the where clause which could be the problem why it takes so long.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing everything in SQL , might be faster.

```
SELECT id, userID 
FROM  table 
WHERE id!= 1111 and created_at >='2017-08-10'
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This will work, but it is taking around 22 seconds to get the query completed when it is running directly on the server. So I think the delay will increase once we take network transport delay into consideration. But yeah, it will return only one record

Comment: @HappyCoder Are the columns ID and Created_at indexed ? How about UserID ? –

Comment: both are indexed fields.

Comment: @HappyCoder did you check with explain if the index are used properly ? Index give no guarentees that it will use the index.

Comment: Yes, It depends how the index is defined . Can you check the explain plan and tell us the result ?

Answer (score 0):

May this will help

```
SELECT userID
  FROM table AS t1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(userID)
                        FROM table)) AS userID)
        AS t2
 where id!= 1111 and created_at >='2017-08-10'
 ORDER BY t1.userID ASC
 LIMIT 1
```